# Use of "then" as "therefore"

Tags: adverbs, time, consequence

I am confused about the following use of *then*:

> «I can't come to Bristol in the afternoon, sorry» «Let's meet around
>   noon, then.»
>
> «I can't do it, I am sorry.» «Well, I'll do it, then!»

I normally say sentences like these when I speak, but it may be just out of imitation, because I am still not sure whether this use of *then* is correct.

Comment: Then means in that case: "In that case, let's meet around noon." Therefore is closer to because. You aren't meeting because of this, you are, however, rescheduling because of it. "Therefore, we rescheduled."

Answer (score 1):

"Then" introduces an implication of previously stated conditions.  "Therefore" introduces the conclusion of an argument that depends on previous statements.  Ordinarily, conclusions and implications correspond, but not always.  Compare

> If pigs had wings, then they could fly.
>    Pigs have wings.  Therefore, they can fly.

Comment: In other news, penguins have wings. :P (Sorry, couldn't help myself.)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple idiomatic uses for ***then*** as an adverb. The one to which you refer is OED sense 5  (then = that being the case, therefore etc), of which there are examples from as early as the 10th century.

> 5. (As a particle of inference, often unemphatic or enclitic.) That being the case; since that is so; on that account; therefore,
>      consequently, as may be inferred; so. now then: see now then at now
>      adv. 6.
>
> 971   Blickl. Hom. 39   Us is þonne mycel nedþearf þæt we gebugon to
>   him.
>
> c1230   Hali Meid. 5   Nis ha þenne sariliche..akast & in to þewdom
>   idrahen.
>
> 1297   R. Gloucester's Chron. (Rolls) 2491   Sire graunte me þanne..As
>   moche place as mid a þuong ich may aboute tille.
>
> a1400  (▸a1325)    Cursor Mundi (Gött.) l. 5987   Wend on þann, siþen
>   ȝe wil ga.
>
> c1475  (▸?c1400)    Apol. Lollard Doctr. (1842) 4   It is certayn þan,
>   þowe he be his seruaunt.
>
> 1539   Bible (Great)  2 Sam. iii. 18   Now then do it.
>
> 1546   Wycklyffes Wycket sig. A.iiii,   Why shoulde it then be taken
>   awaye frome vs.
>
> 1602   Shakespeare Merry Wives of Windsor ii. ii. 36   Fal. Good den
>   faire wife. Quic. Not so ant like your worship. Fal. Faire mayd then.
>
> a1616   Shakespeare As you like It (1623) iv. iii. 174   Well then,
>   take a good heart, and counterfeit to be a man.
>
> 1669   Milton Paradise Lost (new ed.) Verse sig. a4,   This neglect
>   then of Rime so little is to be taken for a defect..that [etc.].
>
> 1773   O. Goldsmith She stoops to Conquer v. 93   Hast. This is a
>   riddle. Tony. Riddle me this then.
>
> 1821   Scott Kenilworth II. viii. 203   ‘Ha!’ said the Countess,
>   hastily; ‘that rumour then is true, Janet.’
>
> 1884   W. C. Smith Kildrostan 86   We give up our cruise, then, after
>   all?